# Breakpoint not triggered inside lambda expresion used n CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Supplier) (not due to Lazy execution)

Tags: java, asynchronous, breakpoints, completable-future

I have a code that creates a CompletableFuture with supplyAsync using lambda as methods argument. I'm obtaining the result of the CompletableFuture so the lambda is executed. However when I put breakpoints in this lambda, they are not triggered ever. This is (as far as I know) not a case of lazy execution, because I am calling .get() on the returned object. Also I know that the code is executed since when I change behaviour of the lambda, the return value from caller is different (I used super trivial lambda with "return SomeEnumType.SOMETHING" to test it). Also as you can see the issue is not due to conditions since breakpoints are in statements that arent put in any conditional code.

It is worth noting that I'm pretty new to java, so I might miss out some obvious thing. However, I have years of programming experience (mainly in c++).

```
private CompletableFuture<SomeEnumType> calleeFunction()
{
    CompletableFuture<SomeEnumType> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync({
        TypeA variableA = classVariableA; // breakpoint on this line
        TypeB variableB = variableA.createTypeB();  // breakpoint on this line
        if ( conditionone)
        { 
             return SomeEnumType.OK
        } else {
             return SomeEnumType.NOT_OK
        }
    });
    return future;
}

private SomeEnumType callerFunction(){
    CompletableFuture<SomeEnumType> future = calleeFunction();
    return future.get();
}
```

Comment: could you please specify the IDE that you are using?

Comment: IntelliJ Ultimate 2021.1. The breakpoints are set to suspend "All".

Comment: Mute breakpoints button is not pressed right?

Comment: It is not. The breakpoints anywhere outside of lambda - caller function, supplyAsync and return future - are all triggered. Just the ones inside lambda are not triggered even tho the lambda is executed.

Comment: refer this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/using-breakpoints.html#productivity-tips

Comment: I read the tips and the statuses and everything seems fine. I don't think I'm falling into any of these. Also the status is suspending and verified (red dot with explamation mark)

Comment: I'm able to stop at the breakpoint with no issues. Doubt this will help, but could you set breakpoints on the return statements? Does that do anything?

Comment: I managed to get the code to debugbreak by putting breakpoint on a class member variable that is accessed inside the lambda. This breakpoint is triggered and I can step through the lambda code this way.